# What do the stats do in Golf Story?

Tags: golf-story

When leveling up in Golf Story, I get the option to level up Power (average drive), Purity (degree draw), Strike (accuracy), Ability (degree control), or Spin (RPM).

While Power and Strike seem pretty self-explanatory, I'm not sure what the other stats are.

**What does each stat do in Golf Story?**

[image: Golf Story - level up screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the game mechanics have changed but after playing around with them a bit I've come up with

Power - Max distance the ball can travel through the air.

Purity - The player's natural draw or fade on the ball. This is reflected in the preview line so you do not have to adjust for it. Increasing this stat past the middle will add a fade (it says slice) to the ball, so if you want to hit it straight keep it centered.

Strike - This for sure increases the purple section of the gauge, decreasing the penalty of being off on the right side diamond. If this stat is all the way down 1cm off is like 20% off due to the small size of the purple zone, so if the zone is larger from increasing this stat, being 1cm off can be just 5% off center. Basically this stat will reduce hook and slice penalties. I have read a lot saying it decreases power penalty for missing the left diamond too, I have not seen enough to confirm this.

Ability - Increases your ability to shape your shot. This is in conjunction with the purity ability. So you can add a fade to dissipate your natural draw to hit it straight, or if you already have a natural draw/fade you can add on to it. This will also enable you to flop or punch the ball for a desired landing.

Spin - Increasing this stat will increase your roll after the ball lands. This stat seems to be the least useful. You do not have control of this spin like you would in most golf games, and often you don't want the ball to roll forward because that's just another variable to factor in when aiming your shot.  There has been times where I feel my approaches are better with spin, there may be a mechanic that spins the ball towards the hole when overshooting it, but this is hard to confirm and could be my imagination.

When I start a new game I find it best to just focus on Power and Purity. Being accurate in this game isnt too hard, but driving distance can be a hole changer. Increasing your purity to straight will also increase your driving distance due to less energy being used in the arc of the ball.

Answer (score 6):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/7313vc/what_does_each_stat_do_in_golf_story/) explains all of the stats in Golf Story quite well:

> Power - how powerful you hit the ball and therefore how far it can go. The reason all the other stats detract when you upgrade this is that it becomes harder to control other factors the further you hit a ball. So keep the other factors in check, but not too high, because sometimes you'll want to undershoot something, or give it curve, etc.
>
> Purity - How true your shot will be to what you want it. Like when your little checker thing hits far away from the center in the purple gauge, it will cause it to curve, right? Purity helps to correct that. Higher purity, the straighter your shot.
>
> Strike - Like the purity one, but with the first gauge instead of the second gauge. You're trying to match it up with the gauge all the way on the left, right? And if you accidentally go way off, then your ball will have a lot less power, right? So if you upgrade this a bunch, your ball will do a lot better at shots where your initial gauge didn't line up well.
>
> Ability - This helps your spin, either in hit point mode, or when you want to hold L/R to add a little extra spin. It does NOT have to do with fixing the purple gauge though. This is purposeful spin ability whereas purity is for correcting accidental spin.
>
> Spin - Will help balls' RPM (rotations per minute, a normal IRL golfer will have one at a few thousand, for reference). Potentially allowing the ball to roll a little longer to get into the whole.

Comment: The random smatterings of bad spelling/grammar in that post can drive a person mad.